# OleDBException in Update statement

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkiay.png)` public void Update(Person oldperson, Person newPerson)
        {
            try
            {

```
            command.CommandText ="Update TPersons SET [Password1]=?,[Name1]=?,[Expertise]=?,[Email id]=?,[Mobile]=?,[Phone no]=?,[Address]=? WHERE [ID]=?";
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Para1", newPerson.Password11));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Para2", newPerson.Name11));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Para3", newPerson.Expertise1));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Para4", newPerson.Email1));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Para5", newPerson.Mobile1));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Para6", newPerson.Phone1));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Para7", newPerson.Address1));

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using this code to update in my access database c# project using visual studio.This is showing me an OleDBException was unhandled.Syntax Error in UPDATE statement.Please help me rsolve this .Thanku !

Comment: `,[Address[) VALUES`do you see the problem ?

Comment: I am still getting an exception saying syntax error in UPDATE statement. !

Comment: So edit your question with the complete message of the exception. Also see my answer below

Comment: I have tried all the three possibilities.(two of which are commented ).And none of them are working.I am willing to provide entire code too if it helps me solve this !

Comment: the strange [ is a problem, but also the parameters name. If I remember well jet accept just positional parameters coded as a '?'

Comment: you are suggesting that I change it to:
\\ command.CommandText = "Update TPersons ([Password1],[Name1],[Expertise],[Email id],[Mobile],[Phone no],[Address]) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE [ID]=@oldperson.[Id] " ;

Comment: You need to also add a parameter for the `WHERE` clause. Also see my updated answer regarding the `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many problems/errors:

**first this** : `,[Address[) VALUES`

then you have tried to use a parameterized update statement, which by default is a good thing, but you did it wrong (for the sql statement ) and also didn`t add any parameters to yout command object ( at least what is shown in your code ).

Check out the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a proper parameterized query.

As you are using an access database the default placeholder for a parameter is a `?` . Other than qith sqlcommand parameters these needs to be assigned in the exact same order.

So here comes some **untested code** to give you a start:

```
command.CommandText = "Update TPersons SET [Password1]=?,[Name1]=?,[Expertise]=?,[Email id]=?,[Mobile]=?,[Phone no]=?,[Address]=? WHERE [ID]=?" ;
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Para1",newPerson.Password11));
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Para2",newPerson.Name11));
```

... and so on

Read this for examples of using parameters in OldeDB (access) or SQL Server:

[Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This is my update statement for AN ms access database.Are all of the three ways equally incorrect?
Sorry i am just a beginner at this !

Comment: I tried this ,but am still geting an error saying syntax error in UPDATE statement !

Comment: So please edit your question to show your current code. At the best also without commented lines.

Comment: I have entered the  edited code and am still getting that Oledbexception was unhandled.
No value given for one or more parameters.

Comment: You need to provide a parameter for the `WHERE [ID]=?` like i have written in the comment to your question.

Comment: Could you help me this one more error..One or more values are prohibited by the validation rule '=Now()' set for 'TPersons.Date1'.  Enter a value that the expression for this field can accept...
I dont know how to set it..I have used newperson.Date11 = DateTime.Now.Date;

Comment: Sorry, i have no clue about validation rules. Maybe start a new question about this specific topic.

Comment: Date1 is a field of the access database whose default value has been set to now(),so that the time of modification of row gets recorded on its own.

Comment: @user3815860 You should not have a validation rule = Now(), but basically what is saying is that Date1 must be today.

Comment: @user3815860 There is a big difference between a validation rule and a default value. A default value is only used on insert.